# Eclipse method names to bold

Tags: java, eclipse

After writing a lot of methods in Eclipse and going through my code after a longer time I am finding hard to search through all my methods and find the one I am looking for. I was thinking to put all my method names text to the bold, but couldn't find a proper way to do it. Is there any option in Preferences to put just the method name characters to the bold?

Comment: what about `window->show view->outline` menu which helps to find methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Window -> Preferences. There, go to Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring. Expand the >Java button. Select Method declarations. Now, click 'Enable' check box and then the 'Bold' check box.

There are many other ways to see a list of methods in a class:

1. Use Ctrl+O within a class to see the list of methods in a class
2. Use Window -> Show View -> Outline to enable the Outline view which shows the list of methods (and public fields) in a class